# XQuery: How to put a variable in a URL?

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm still relatively new to Xpath.

I'm wondering how exactly I would use a variable to generate a url.

For instance, one application I'm using has a different XML document URL for each date.

So one URL might be http://www.example/2014-09-01.xml.

I need to retrieve a large number of these URLs based on the current date. I'm not sure how one would insert a $variable into a statement like doc("URL")/filters

Comment: The accepted answer makes it clear that the question was really asked only about XQuery, not XPath. Editing appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let $URI := concat('http://www.example/', $date, '.xml')
return doc($URI)
```

Comment: I was aware that syntax was available for XQuery, but wasn't aware that it worked with XPath as well. Thanks!

Comment: ...well, let me redact that comment -- now your answer is quite certainly XQuery-specific rather than applying to both.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It doesn't :/ Sorry! I immediately doubted my answer, tested it, and fixed it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Right, OP tagged the question as XQuery. Not many other places he might be using XPath...

Comment: I see both XQuery and XPath tags, and read that as a question intended to cover both languages.

Comment: This appears to work. I'm using Basex ---- which doesn't let you input a $var directly into the URL.

Comment: @JohnBabson, ...because if you're trying to do HTTP retrieval in BaseX, there's an explicit API intended for that use. (If you'd asked your _real_ question, perhaps we could have described it).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I suppose to be more general I could drop the `let`: `doc(concat('http://www.example/', $date, '.xml'))`. But for questions like this I typically make the assumption that the environment is XQuery (or XSLT if it's tagged XSLT/XPath)...for the uninitiated, it's not always clear the relationships between the XML standards languages.

Comment: If you are using BaseX, you can also use `||` to concatenate strings, which I find easier to read, i.e. `'http://www.example/' || $date || '.xml'`. Adding to Charles' remark, take a look at the HTTP module: http://docs.basex.org/wiki/HTTP_Module

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for variables in XPath is simply `$varname`. So:

```
doc($url)/filters
```

The method for passing in variables in from an out-of-band tool or processing engine varies with that processing engine. With XMLStarlet, for instance, that might be:

```
xmlstarlet sel --var url "http://www.example.com/$date.xml"
```

...or, with the BaseX command-line interface:

```
basex -b'$url='"http://www.example.com/$date.xml"
```

Comment: In BaseX CLI you could also write `-burl=` instead of `-b'$url='`, i.e. omitting the $ and thus the shell escaping.